# Omitting the following parentheses

Tags: beamer

```
      \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} (this is necessary for old beamer versions)
 %\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}

 \usetheme{Madrid}
 \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
  \definecolor{kaiscyan}{RGB}{0,139,139}

     \BeforeBeginEnvironment{proposition}{%
   \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=kaiscyan}
     \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=kaiscyan!20!white}
      }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{proposition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
        }

       \begin{document}

       \begin{frame}
   \begin{proposition}[\hfill{[\ding{43} The authors (year)]}]
       A proposition.
   \end{proposition}
    \end{frame}

      \end{document}
```

> I want to omit the following parentheses

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change the relevant beamer template. If you are always using the hand there you can add it to the template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} (this is necessary for old beamer versions)
 %\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}

 \usetheme{Madrid}
 \makeatletter
 \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
 \definecolor{kaiscyan}{RGB}{0,139,139}


   \BeforeBeginEnvironment{proposition}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
    {%
     \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
     {%
     \inserttheoremheadfont
     \inserttheoremname
     \inserttheoremnumber
     \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else
     \hfill[\ding{43} \inserttheoremaddition]%
     \fi
     }%
    }%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=kaiscyan}%
     \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=kaiscyan!20!white}%
     }
    \AfterEndEnvironment{proposition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
        }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
   \begin{proposition}[The authors (year)]
       A proposition.
   \end{proposition}

   \begin{proposition}[another]
       A proposition.
   \end{proposition}

   \begin{proposition}
       A proposition.
   \end{proposition}
  \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you however I will not use always the hand

Comment: Then change `\hfill[\ding{43} \inserttheoremaddition]%` to `\hfill \insertheoremaddition`. Then your original input will work.

Comment: Thank you. Also please why the proposition are numbred?

Comment: Because of the `\inserttheoremnumber`. If you don't want it remove it.